# Getting white page after uploading my Laravel 5.2 application to server

Tags: php, git, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

I've already installed composer on the production application. I've set permissions on the storage folder (775, 777). The web server is configured to look for `index.php`. That's the first time I try to deploy a Laravel application. Something that messed me up was that after I used the push command to upload my Laravel application using git I looked inside the Laravel storage folder in the server and I realized that the storage folder had basically only the directory structure of the storage folder of my local Laravel application, many files were missing like `laravel.log` among others. I assumed that it was because I didn't ran `composer install` on the server. After running `composer install` things continued the same.

Comment: Check your server logs (`/var/log/(nginx/httpd/apache2)`) and your laravel logs for a hint.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I  tried to add a dependency manually to bootstrap/autoload.php as I was testing Laravel and I forgot to remove it. Nginx described exactly the error.